# Running sample plugin in hawt.io using Maven hawtio:camel command

Tags: java, apache-camel, hawtio

I am trying to run sample plugin from

https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-plugin-examples/simple-plugin

I was able to create WAR of that plugin and placed in resource folder so it can be picked  but when i am trying to run command

```
mvn hawtio:camel
```

I can't see simple tab in hawt.io console .

According to following documentation it should be picked

https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/docs/HowPluginsWork.md#separate-deployment-unit

Please let me know in case i am missing something. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Are you using Hawtio 1.5.x right?  What is the "resource folder" you've placed the war in?

Comment: yes i am using 1.5.x . Resource folder which created as part of Maven project.it's in class path. I have created a folder name plugins into that and placed war overthere

Comment: The doc doesn't say that you can put war files in src/main/resources and mvn hawtio:camel picks them up. Instead try using a webapp container eg. Tomcat and put the wars into its deploy folder.

Comment: But i need to run using Maven that's project requirement. I put in resource folder because that's already in class path